# How to read line by line from Spring Webflux FilePart DataBuffer

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

I am using Spring Webflux to upload files. In my case i have to upload a CSV file.
From what i can collect with the searches i have done is this code:

```
public Flux<String> getLines(Flux<FilePart> filePartFlux) {
    return filePartFlux.flatMap(filePart ->
            filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            })
            .map(this::processAndGetLinesAsList)
            .flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
}
```

But during this process ,if the dataBuffer reaches its capacity , it will read the last line partially, and hence an incorrect csv will be processed if i pass the half value.
Is there any method by which i can be certail that the filw is read line by line instead of the Flux.

Example :
Databuffer 1 emitted from flux contains:

```
<name,title,address
joe,engineer,straight way california,
mike,doc >
```

Databuffer 2 from Flux contains :

```
<tor,hatlway street,
jeremy,plumber,newyork>
```

The solution that i have in my mind currently is to maintain a stack where i will push incomplete records by comparing the CSV splitted header length with splitted current record length, and in case if its less , then pop emelemt from stack and join the two strings.
I am hoping that there is an efficient way to do all this.

Answer (score -2):

```
filePartFlux is Flux<FilePart>

val buffer = DataBufferUtils.join(filePartFlux).block()
val reader =  buffer.asInputStream(true).bufferedReader()
while(reader.ready()) {
    val line = reader.readLine()
    println("$line")
}
```

---

@Vishal jotshi, or this is better:

```
DataBufferUtils.join(filePartFlux).subscribe { 
 buffer -> buffer.asInputStream(true).bufferedReader().use {
 reader -> while(reader.ready()) {
    val line = reader.readLine()
    println("$line")
}
```

}

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongside code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value."

Comment: Blocking and joining filePartFlux will load all of file data into memory which is what i am trying to avoid.So i would not suggest doing this.

Comment: Using .join will read everything into memory.